# If I have a shiny Nincada, what happens?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

If I have a Shiny Nincada, and I evolve it with an extra spot in my party, what happens? Do I get a Shiny Ninjask and Shiny Shedinja, or just a Shiny Ninjask with a normal Shedinja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The way that a Pokemon's "shininess" is determined is based on three values: The Original Trainer's ID, their secret ID, and the individual Pokemon's personality value. Given that Shedinja retains the original Nincada's personality value, a shiny Nincada will produce a shiny Ninjask *and* a shiny Shedinja upon evolution.

Side note, the exact formula used to calculate shininess is:

```
(TrainerID xor SecretID) xor (PersonalityValue31..16 xor PersonalityValue15..0)
```

Where `PersonalityValue31..16` and `PersonalityValue15..0` represent the highest and lowest 16 bits of the 32-bit personality value respectively.